# Django ORM can't get value from specific field

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2, django-orm

My old project uses django 2.1.7, drf 3.9.2, psycopg2==2.7.7, and postgresql in AWS RDS.
I found a strange thing that orm couldn't get some values from database.
Actually, there were real values in my database.
ORM works well in other values in other columns, but some in specific value, it weren't work.

the field looks like this:

```
class ExamResult(models.Model):
    task_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, primary_key=True)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    result = models.CharField(max_length=5000, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
```

the value in DB looks like:

> - character varying(5000) in postgres
> - 0_ 46 46 .... 52 53 50 43 41 54 52 /

the result in my server or shell is just None.
other values work well...

result:

```
"task_id": “0x888n"
“subject”: <subject object>
“result”:None
“description”: “exam ver.2"
```

Comment: Can you please show the exact query?

Comment: the query is just this: target = ExamResult.objects.filter(task_id=req_id).last()
/ I just editted my main text!

Comment: This query returns the last entry in the `ExamResult` model and from your edit, I can see it's returning an object. Or are you saying the `result` field of the returned object is `None` is that your question

Comment: the result of my main text is this: print(target.task_id) -> "0x888n" / printt(target.subject) -> <subject object> / .... .   I wonder this: the actual value of target.result is  '0_ 46 46 .... 52 53 50 43 41 54 52 /', but I got just None

Comment: Can you run `ExamResult.objects.all()` and share the result to be sure that you are not querying an entry with an empty entry in the `result` field.

Comment: I tried that, and I found some clues to solve this problem! some values are shown as those in the database, but others are not. Maybe I need to compare two kinds.

Comment: Wow, it was all mistake. I got the wrong id from my teammate, so I checked the wrong object again and again! So, if orm shows null value, then the actual result value of an object is null. Anyway, I appreciate you to help me. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out :). Cheers!